# Cancel next scheduled build of project A when project B is building

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Suppose I have a project `A`, scheduled to build every hour `03:00`, `04:00`, `05:00`, etc. `B` starts building at `03:30` and finishes at `03:35`. How can I cancel the `04:00` scheduled build of `A` so that A would next build at `05:00`? Project `B` doesn't has a schedule.

Comment: What is the relationship between jobs/projects A & B?

Comment: None, as far as Jenkins relationship goes...

Comment: See if [this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67568849) works out for you, so that I can change this to an answer!

Comment: I have used this plugin; however how do I cancel next scheduled build of another project using it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it in another way - instead of cancelling the build; I simply put a step to quit without actually building in project `A` if a file exists - and added a step in `B` to touch the file!

```
In A:

if [ -f /tmp/flag ]; then
  rm /tmp/flag
  echo "First trigger since A; quitting"
  exit;
fi

In B:

touch /tmp/flag
```